# People take or takes?

Tags: verbs, american-english

Which one is correct?

> 1. People takes
> 2. People take

And:

> 1. People does the same thing?
> 2. People do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples, people is a plural noun. People take. People do.